# Printing Arrays in Matrix Format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python list (`A`) and each entry of the list is a list that I would like to print out in matrix form (to compare with some other output).  I can mostly accomplish this with:

`print(np.array(A[i]).reshape(dim1,dim2),'\n')`.

However, I would also like to control the formatting of the output, i.e., scientific notation, number of decimal places, etc.  In that regard, I tried

`print("{0:.3f}".format(np.array(A[i]).reshape(2*n+1,2*n+1)),'\n')`

which throws the error `non-empty format string passed to object.__format__`.

How to I format the output and reshape it into something that looks like a matrix for printing?